# Redirect to the correct place

Tags: php, laravel, url, redirect

When I type the following I visit my website:

`mywebsite.com`

and when I type the following I also visit my website:

`mywebsite.com///////`

May I know how to prevent this issue?

I want to make laravel redirect from `"mywebsite.com///////"` to `"mywebsite.com"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on # remove this line if already in your .htaccess file
# Remove multiple slashes after domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]
```